# java connecting to access database problem

Tags: ms-access, odbc, jdbc-odbc

When trying to connect the access db i get this error: 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
this is my code:

```
Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");        
DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=d:\task.accdb", "" , "");
```

I' guessing it have to do someting with the fact that it is 64bit?
How can this be fixed? and if not are they any other databases like access that I can use?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: Post your connection string, please.

Comment: @cularis: Iv'e updated the connection string..

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string there is unescaped `\`. Try with this string:

```
DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=d:\\task.accdb", "" , "");
```

You can also create System DSN for your database (in case of 64 bit systems you can do in in both 32 bit and 64 bit environments) and then use connect string like:

```
jdbc:odbc:northwind
```

Comment: I tried it and it still gave me the same error.. I think it has to do something with the fact it is 64bit..

Comment: Try to create System DNS for you database in both 32 and 64 bit environments.